# How to Get previous month and current year in Teradata/SQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, teradata-sql-assistant

I need a simple TERADATA/SQL statement which gives previous month and current year in the following format. In this case as '03 2022'.

I have tried to solve a similar request for current date in required format as '04/15/2022' by exec the below command

> SELECT CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') (CHAR(12)) as 'New_format'.

But now I am struggling to get exact value as 'mm yyyy' which gives previous month and current year.

I have tried several CAST and CONCAT, but none seems to be working. Please guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why tagged mysql if database is Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1),'mm yyyy')
```

which returns VARCHAR - could then CAST to CHAR if needed, or

```
CAST(CAST(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1) AS FORMAT'mmbyyyy') as CHAR(7))
```

or legacy syntax

```
ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1)(FORMAT'mmbyyyy')(CHAR(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it as a comment but I dont have enought reputation.

`SELECT DATE - INTERVAL '1' MONTH`

More about it in link:
https://etl-sql.com/teradata-date-functions/

Comment: Thank you for responding, but i need the proper format. . it is giving as '3/15/2022' i need previous month and current year as '03 2022' only

Comment: Adding or subtracting INTERVAL MONTH may fail due to some months having more days than others, e.g. on 2022-05-31 subtracting 1 from the month would yield 2022-04-31 which is invalid